# Laptop suddenly not seeing wifi and bluetooth

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

While on the laptop, everything was normal, and all of the sudden the wifi options from the bottom right disappeared.

I've reinstalled windows and wifi still doesn't show up, when usually it would just detect the wirless network and connect.

Is it Possible to be a hardware problem ? Are the bluetooth and wifi receivers on the same board, and maybe something  happened with that ?

Comment: Hi Radu, welcome to Superuser. 
If you look in your device manager, do you see the card listed?

Answer (score 0):

Wireless and Bluetooth are often on the same card or card device. This makes it easier for Airplane Mode to turn both off.

1. Does your laptop have a Wireless button or Function key? and did that get disabled / turned off. Check that.
2. Windows 10 Network Settings:  Is Airplane Mode ON?  Turn Airplane Mode OFF.
3. Look in Device Manager and make sure the Bluetooth and Wireless drivers are both shown as installed and active (no red or orange marks).

Orange marks indicate disabling by hardware issue or some other disabling.

These are the things that affect Wireless.

[image]

Comment: No Wireless or function key, airplane mode is turned off and in device manager I have an orange mark on the Intel Wireless-AC 9560, and under other devices everything has a orange mark.

Base system device
PCI Data Aquisition and SIgnal Processing Controller, Comunication controller, Bus Controller, and 4 showing as unknown devices.

Comment: I fixed it ... Aparently vpn and proxy was on for some reason ... and that somehow made nothing show up ... I don't know how that got turned on. Thank you for the help

Comment: Normally orange mark might indicate a hardware issue, or disabled by some other activity - in this case VPN likely